# Strings out of Linked Lists, efficient constructor for an object

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list

I'm struggling with building a linked list constructor in an object called `LString`. The constructor builds strings out of linked lists instead of arrays. Another file tests the object to verify its ability, and when I run that file with my constructor, and a `toString()` method, I receive this error:

```
Running constructor, length, toString tests (10 tests)
Starting tests: ..FF......
Time: 0.00

2 failures:
1) t02aEmptyConstructorIsEmptyString(LStringTest$EmptyStringTest)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        ... 1 more
        at LString.<init>(LString.java:45)
        at LStringTest$EmptyStringTest.t02aEmptyConstructorIsEmptyString(LStringTest.java:193)
        ... 9 more
2) t02bEmptyConstructorHasZeroLength(LStringTest$EmptyStringTest)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        ... 1 more
        at LString.<init>(LString.java:45)
        at LStringTest$EmptyStringTest.t02bEmptyConstructorHasZeroLength(LStringTest.java:198)
        ... 9 more

Test Failed! (2 of 10 tests failed.)
```

I believe I'm building the linked list correctly, and creating an `LString` object incorrectly, though I'm having trouble finding out why. Any advice is appreciated, trying to learn java.

Here's my code:

```
public class LString    {

     node front;
     int size;

     private class node {
          char data;
          node next;

          public node (){
          }

          public node (char newData){
                this.data = newData;
          }

          public node (char newData, node newNext){
                this.data = newData;
                this.next = newNext;
          }


     }

     public LString(){
          this.size =   0;
          this.front =  null;
     }
     public LString(String original)    {
          this.size = original.length();
          this.front =  new node(original.charAt(0));
          node curr = this.front;

          for   (int i =1; i <  original.length(); i++) {
                curr.next = new node(original.charAt(i));
                curr = curr.next;

          }


     }
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        node curr = front;
        while (curr != null){

            result.append(curr.data);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you pass an empty string to the second constructor. In this case this following line throws an exception.

```
this.front =  new node(original.charAt(0));
```

because `chatAt(0)` does not exists (0 is out of the bound). You can guard this constructor with an `if` condition to prevent this case.